# Get country, county and street name from layers

Tags: here-api

currently we fetch the address information from reverse.geocoder but we are also using rme and pde so i was wondering if I can everything without reverse geocoder call?

What we need at the end is

STREET NAME, COUNTY, COUNTRY

Country and street name we have, but the county (federal state name) is only an id in ROAD_ADMIN_FC. Is there a way to map it to a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder API is the best to get street, county and country information all in one query. But depending on your usecase, you can also check out ROAD_NAME_FC* and ROAD_ADMIN_NAMES_FC* to get these information. Refer tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layers?region=WEU&release=18135&url_root=pde.api.here.com to check the responses you can get from these PDE layers.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example on how to parse that name string to get the name of the e.g. city in the native form? So the name of the city it has in the country it is. Which of the entries is the native name? First, last? Is there a special order?